# Bandwidth and throughput of a WCF connection

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-3.0

I have a NET.TCP WCF server and client application and would like to provide stats in the server side component for the bandwidth, TTL etc for each client connected.

To get TTL I could implement a new method to bounce between the client and server and measure the time difference, and to measure the traffic I could simply count the bytes in my messages but I wondered if there are any built in stats in the ServiceHost that would provide what I need.

Counting the bytes I have in my objects might also be misleading since the binding will apply binary encoding for the data anyway.

Comment: I suspect you could get some numbers from a custom MessageInspector (fairly sure I've written such here on stackoverflow), but to get an accurate picture including transport effects, wireshark may be better.

Comment: Thanks Marc.  I'll implement MessageInspector add accumulate bytes out and in and derive bytes/second from that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combining [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2007/08/23/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector.aspx) blog post and trawling the online docs I have implemented a Message Inspector, custom behaviour and applied it to my service.

Since my service is Duplex, to capture all the traffic, I need to add message inspectors to both the server side end point and the callback client runtime.  This point seems to be missing from many of the online examples.

**Custom Inspector**

```
public class EndPointMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector, IClientMessageInspector 
{
    static long _bytesWritten = 0;
    static long _bytesRead = 0;

    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        MessageBuffer buffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
        request = buffer.CreateMessage();
        _bytesRead += buffer.CreateMessage().ToString().Length;
        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        if (reply != null)
        {
            MessageBuffer buffer = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
            reply = buffer.CreateMessage();
            _bytesWritten += buffer.CreateMessage().ToString().Length;
        }
    }

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        // No replies expected from Duplex call backs
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        if (request != null)
        {
            MessageBuffer buffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
            request = buffer.CreateMessage();
            _bytesWritten += buffer.CreateMessage().ToString().Length;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Custom Service Behaviour**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class GatherThroughputBehaviour : Attribute, IServiceBehavior, IEndpointBehavior
{
    #region IServiceBehavior Members
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers.Count; i++)
        {
            ChannelDispatcher channelDispatcher = serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers[i] as ChannelDispatcher;
            if (channelDispatcher != null)
            {
                foreach (EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher in channelDispatcher.Endpoints)
                {
                    EndPointMessageInspector inspector = new EndPointMessageInspector();
                    endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(inspector);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }
    #endregion

    #region IEndpointBehavior Members
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new EndPointMessageInspector());
        endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.CallbackClientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new EndPointMessageInspector());
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) 
    { 
        return; 
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**Apply the Behaviour to my Service**

```
[GatherThroughputBehaviour]
public class TunnelServer : IMyContract
{
    ...
}
```